# Warning message: Passing 'MessageDetailController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>'

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am guessing this is a basic error... but can't seem to figure out the following build error (warning)...

```
Passing 'MessageDetailController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>'
```

On the following line...

```
controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```

I have the following declared in the header file...

```
@interface MessageDetailController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

instead of `controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;`

because you have imported the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol and i think you are trying to send the mail.

if i am wrong i.e you are trying to send the Message then you should Adopt the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` Protocol,In this case no need to change the single line of code.

[For more detailed Knowledge of MessageUI Framework take a look of this Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html)

Comment: I am trying to use the text messaging interface - note the line to set the mailComposeDelegate works where I am using the email interface.

Comment: SO in this case you just need to Adopt the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and just use ypur previous Code  as you were using the `controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;`. and one thing this Functionality only applicable in Iphone device.

Answer (score 18):

You could also try this line of code

```
controller.mailComposeDelegate = (id)self;
```

Comment: Worked like charm :-) and cleaned up the warnings with this nasty one.

Comment: solved my: assigning incompatible type Master View Controller const __strong to id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> :)